# How do i integrate Admob with Google Analytics and not Firebase Analytics

Tags: android

i want to add Google analytics to my AdMob app,but the AdMob Accoujnt says that you can link the ad to firebase analytics..

Answer (score 0):

firebase analytics is optional.
you may skip that .